# How can I create a timer/stopwatch with custom time speed

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to create a stopwatch in Javascript which is slower than usual. Where 1 second takes 30 real life seconds to complete.
No start/stop buttons are required, the code just needs to display a timer that starts from 0 years 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds and goes up at a custom, modifiable speed. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

use `setInterval` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to update a variable that is the current time on the watch as a variable. setInterval takes in a delay, so you can custom configure that to change the speed of the timer. Whenever someone changes the speed you need to kill the last setInterval with clearInterval() and pass in the reference to the running interval.

Read a bit of that documentation and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

agree with other answer, `setInterval` is the most suitable method, here is an example which starts from the current date/time and moves at a slower rate of 30 real seconds = 1 program second:

```
var tcount = 1;
var step = 30000;
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toDateString()+' '+d.toLocaleTimeString());
var timr = setInterval(()=> {
  d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds()+tcount);
  console.log(d.toDateString()+' '+d.toLocaleTimeString());
}, step);
```